# Export element value if exists

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to export http links if element is not empty. Currently I am using this XSLT template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="url1" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="url2" />
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="url3" /> 
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample XML:

```
<rss>
    <item>
        <name>1</name>
        <url1>http://image1.jpg</url1>
        <url2></url2>
        <url3>http://image3.jpg</url3>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>2</name>
        <url1>http://image1.jpg</url1>
        <url2></url2>
        <url3></url3>
    </item>
</rss>
```

Everything is fine, except that there is a new line in the output:

```
http://image1.jpg

http://image3.jpg
http://image1.jpg
```

Is there any way to avoid these new lines? Currently I am using a linux tool to remove these lines, but it would be nice to format directly in the XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the element's content for emptiness before copying it like this

```
<xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(url1) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="url1" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length(url2) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="url2" />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="string-length(url3) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="url3" />        
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

```
http://image1.jpg
http://image3.jpg
http://image1.jpg
```

Or, if you want it a little bit more generalized, use the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(local-name(),'url')]">
    <xsl:if test="string-length(.) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write additional rules inside `<xsl:template match="...">`. Maybe try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="item">
...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(*) and not(normalize-space())]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that with XSLT 2 or 3 if you want to output some items with a certain separator string you can use `<xsl:value-of select="select items here" separator="separator string"/>` so your intent and the proposed code can be simplified to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="item">
      <xsl:value-of select="*[starts-with(local-name(), 'url') and normalize-space()]" separator="&#10;"/>
      <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8j